# .NET Core Error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: .net-core, service, regedit

I created a Windows Service starting from my .NET Core project following [this](https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2020/01/28/create-and-install-a-windows-service-from-a-net-core-project/)

After this, I installed correctly it on my working machine and started it.

This is my service class:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace xxx
{
    public class WindowsService
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

            using (var service = new Service())
            {
                ServiceBase.Run(service);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Service : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service()
        {
            ServiceName = "...";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnStart(args);
                Task.Run(() => xxxx);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
        }
    }
}
```

So, I copied the file and installed it also on a server. Here, when I try to start it, I get:

[image: Error showed starting the service]

After this, I start a lot of googling... for example, I tried the following steps :

*Go to Start > Run > and type regedit*

*Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control*

*With the control folder selected, right click in the pane on the right and - select new DWORD Value*

*Name the new DWORD: ServicesPipeTimeout*

*Right-click ServicesPipeTimeout, and then click Modify*

*Click Decimal, type '180000', and then click OK*

*Restart the computer*

The weird point here is that the voice **ServicesPipeTimeout** didn't exist and I created it. Comparing the server with my working machine, there are also other value not present in the server. They are:

- ServicesPipeTimeout
- OsBootstatPath

Here the screenshot of regedit from the server:

[image]

Are these relevant?

I also tried to reinstall the service, recompile my files... how can I fix this problem? **The error appears immediatly, it doesn't wait any timeout!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem when I switched my project to another location.

When I moved the project, I had copied the files in bin/debug folder too. The issue was resolved after I cleared the debug folder and created a new build.

See if this works!

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit old question but someone may find this useful.

So I had the following code in Program.cs:
`builder.SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")`

Changed it to:
`builder.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")`

This seemed to fix the problem for me.
The problem with this error is that it is super generic.
Hopefully MS will give us some log in the future.

Comment: this hint saved me hours of commenting out code and retesting

Answer (score 3):

if you check the windows event viewer under applications it tells you what exactly is the exception that causes this error.

in my case the problem was i published the service in net6 and tried to run it on a pc with net7 installed. apparently it requires the exact major version that was used to publish the app.